# Get EventMessage from message in MS Graph API with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to Get EventMessage from Message in MS Graph API with C# but every time it is showing type as a message instead of EventMessage. Below are the code:-

```
public static Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionPage ReadInbox()
{
   GetAuthenticatedClient();
   var result = new Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionPage();
   List<Graph.QueryOption> options = new List<Graph.QueryOption>
   {
           new Graph.QueryOption("$expand","microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event"),
           new Graph.QueryOption("$filter","isread eq false")
   };

   try
   {
       var response = graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request(options).OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC").GetAsync();

       result = response.Result as Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionPage;

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   { }
```

Call the above method `ReadInbox` to get type and perform some action.

```
var appointments = ReadInbox();
if (appointments != null)
{
    foreach (dynamic request in appointments)
    {
        try
        {
            if (request.GetType().Name.Contains("EventMessage"))
            {
            }
            else if (request.GetType().Name == "Message")
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the IsInstanceOfType method to identify if its an eventMessage. You can also remove the expand option from the query option since eventMessages are fetched anyway as part of the get Messages call.

```
if (appointments != null)
            {
                foreach (dynamic request in appointments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (typeof(EventMessage).IsInstanceOfType(request))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Is an event");
                            Console.WriteLine(request);
                        }                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```